# Sending e-mail with to, cc, bcc maild and body with html

Tags: macos, swift3

I'm trying to write an application which have business cc and bcc was set and mail body has image inside.

1/ I tried using NSSharing services, it can contain images inside the mail 's body but the problem is I cannot set cc and bcc recipient.
NSSharing only have service.recipient, all mail addresses set on this properties with set to "mailto".

2/I tried using MailScheme but the problem is I cannot set image in the body and attachment file.

3/I tried using Script bridge but the problem is like this man's issue:
https://stackoverflow360.com/questions/40897768/scripting-bridge-classes-with-swift-3

I know that if I was using Objective-C, the problem will be solved but my current project uses Swift 3.